# Shut down HSQLDB in server mode from the shell

Tags: hsqldb

How can I stop a running HSQLDB server instance from the shell (e.g. as part of a shell script)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. Replace `dbname` with the name of your database and change credentials if necessary, and adjust the classpath to your system as needed:

```
java -cp $CLASSPATH:/usr/share/java/hsqldbutil.jar:/usr/share/java/hsqldb.jar "org.hsqldb.cmdline.SqlTool" --inlineRc=url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/dbname,user=SA,password= --sql="SHUTDOWN;"
```

If your distro comes with a shell script wrapper for SQL Tool, you can shorten that as:

```
hsqldb-sqltool --inlineRc=url=jdbc:hsqldb:hsql://localhost/dbname,user=SA,password= --sql="SHUTDOWN;"
```

Instead of using `--inlineRc` you can also build an rcfile with the parameters you need and specify that.